# App is asking for Windows credentials with Web Forms autentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication, controller

I have a bizarre issues happening with my MVC .NET application. I am using Web Forms authentication and have no references to Windows Authentication in my web.config. On my local computer I can go to any page without issues but when I publish it out to my staging environment it asks for Windows Authentication for only one controller. This controller is inherited from the same custom controller that I'm using on all other pages.

I figured it was perhaps folder permission issue with IIS but I have verified that Network Service has read rights to the folder.

Is there anything that could cause Windows Authentication while the rest of the site is using Web Forms? It is strange that it is only happening in my staging environment and not my local machine.

Here is my controller code:

```
public class ReportsController : WorkflowController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And here is some of the code from the WorkflowController class:

```
[Authorize]
public abstract class WorkflowController : Controller
{
    /*  When a paramaterless WorkflowController is created this section will override it to 
        pass in a new UserManager*/
    public WorkflowController()
        : this(new UserManager<RediscoverUser>(
                    new UserStore<RediscoverUser>(
                        new UsersDbContext()))) { }

    public WorkflowController(UserManager<RediscoverUser> userManager)
    {

        UserManager = userManager;
        var currentUserId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId(); //get the id of the current user

        if (currentUserId != null)
        {
            AppUser = UserManager.FindById(currentUserId);
            new Task(() => LogActivity(AppUser)).Start(); //Asyncronously log the activity
            db.ChangeDatabase(initialCatalog: AppUser.DatabaseName); //set the db repository to the current users company
        }
    }

    //Set global variables for the workflow controller
    public UserManager<RediscoverUser> UserManager { get; private set; }
    public RediscoverUser AppUser { get; private set; }
    public RediscoverDatabaseEntities db = new RediscoverDatabaseEntities();

    public void LogActivity(RediscoverUser user)
    {
        user.DateOfLastActivity = DateTime.Now;
        UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
    }

    //Override the default Dispose method to include the DatabaseEntities to be disposed of
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Almost all of my controllers are inheriting from this WorkflowController and they are all working just fine. Its just the one `ReportsController` that is giving me the trouble and it is the most simple.

I am using Entity Framework for the Data Access Layer.

Any assistance on this strange issue would be great! Also, any general advice on this custom Controller class would be welcomed :)

Comment: Do you have a directory in the root of your application named Reports?

Comment: @ErikPhilips, no sir. Just the usual MVC folders at the root (bin, content, fonts, images, scripts, views). In the Views folder I have the reports folder with the index.cshtml.

Comment: Have you checked the connection string of the database?

Comment: @ActiveHigh, yeah I checked all connection strings in all projects. In  the IIS connection strings for the web application there is "Integrated Security=SSPI" for a "LocalSqlServer" connection name but I am not using it anywhere in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erik Philips was on the right track with his question in the comments. I renamed the controller to RediscoverReportsController and everything is working now. Not sure why this would've caused issues, perhaps it is reserved somewhere?

Even after changing the name of the controller and republishing the changes, if i go to localhost/reports/index it asks me for Windows Authentication again. I am assuming that asp.net MVC has something tied into the name Reports?

Thanks for you help guys this was driving me nuts!

EDIT: Also, as a side note, the SQL Server instance that the databases are on has SSRS installed so it has a "ReportServer" and "ReportServerTempDB" database on it. I have a feeling that the fact that I was connectiong to the equivilent of localhost/reports/XXXXXX it was trying to connect to SSRS rather than my web application. What a pain!